# Resizing Iframe issue in Chrome only

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, javascript-framework

Okay, here goes. Stack Overflow virgin here but hopefully you guys will be able to help me.

I have been playing around with resizing the height of an iframe based on it's content. The content varies as a user will progress through a series of forms, this means that each submit will result in a new form of which there are 3 forms.

The code below is called when the iframe loads,

```
function checkHeight() {
    var frame=document.getElementById('frame');
    var doc=frame.contentWindow.document;
    var data=doc.getElementById('data');
    alert(data);
    var data_height=data.offsetHeight;
    if(data_height) {
        frame.style.height=data_height + 'px';
        alert('height has been set');
    }
}
```

This is working fine on both mac and pc versions of Mozilla, IE and Safari but I am having a massive issue with chrome. It is not returning a document within the frame. Is this a permissions error or what?!

I have also tried contentDocument but to no avail.

All the documents reside on my server and are all within the same folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure you're going to find a solution to this - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6402

Comment: thanks Alex for the link, some useful stuff but I may still continue searching for a solution.

Comment: I wish you luck buddy. Please comment if you find a solution.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that the forms to display are within the <div id="data"></div> on the child pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit:

I've re-read your question - would it be simpler to just calculate the height inside the iframe's document and call the parent resizing function since they are in the same security sandbox (i.e. on the same domain)?

### Original:

Since a somewhat similar thing happens when the iframes are embedded from a different domain (cannot access iframe..document) I'd speculate this approach would work:

1. First: calculate the document height in the document itself (i.e. inside the iframe).
2. Pass the values to the parent using window.postMessage/hash polling for older browsers. There is [a neat library](http://postmessage.freebaseapps.com/) that takes care of compatibility for you.
3. Receive the value in the parent and resize the iframe accordingly.

Again, this may be overkill, but given that the solution has been tested to do exactly what you're after *between different security sandboxes*, this should also be the case for a simpler scenario if iframes are on the same domain.

That being said, if they *are* on the same domain (as opposed to widgets/non-mashable third party content) is there really need for an iframe? Sounds like it's just a matter of setting up jQuery to make ajax requests and populate container(s) with new data.

Comment: many thanks for this. calling a prent function using this.style.height as a parameter seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

this seems like a fairly straight forward question so i'm not sure why such strange answers, so maybe i missed the boat entirely on this one, but here are my solutions, one is x-domain and the other isn't (note: the open/write/close, is just there to simulate server interaction to make it more obvious what's going on...)

**first x-domain style:**

```
// METHOD #1: postMessage() x-domain (chrome, ff, ie8+, safari, etc)
var d = document,
    iframe = d.createElement('iframe');
iframe.height = 0;
d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iframe);

window.onmessage = function(msg) { 
  iframe.height = parseInt(msg.data, 10);
};

var fd = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
fd.open();
fd.write('<!DOCTYPE ht' + 'ml><ht' + 'ml><he' + 
         'ad><scri' + 'pt>' +
         'window.onload = function(){' +

         'var db = document.body,' +
         'de = document.documentElement;' +

         'window.parent.postMessage(' + 
           'Math.max(db.scrollHeight, de.scrollHeight, db.offsetHeight, de.offsetHeight, db.clientHeight, de.clientHeight),' +
           '"*"' +
         ');' +

         '};</scr' + 'ipt></he' + 'ad><bo' + 
         'dy style="background:#afa"><div style="border:s' +
         'olid 1px black;padding:50px;line-height:50px">method #1: x-domain<b' +
         'r />test<br />test</div></bo' + 'dy></ht' + 
         'ml>');
fd.close();
```

**next more compatible same domain version:**

```
// METHOD #2: manually same-domain (all browsers? [with tweaks] )

var iframe2 = d.createElement('iframe');

iframe2.height = 0;

iframe2.onload = function() {
  var xfd = iframe2.contentDocument || iframe2.contentWindow.document,
      db = xfd.body,
      de = xfd.documentElement;

  iframe2.height = Math.max(db.scrollHeight, de.scrollHeight, db.offsetHeight, de.offsetHeight, db.clientHeight, de.clientHeight);

};

d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iframe2);

fd = iframe2.contentDocument || iframe2.contentWindow.document;
fd.open();
fd.write('<!DOCTYPE ht' + 'ml><ht' + 'ml><he' + 
         'ad></he' + 'ad><bo' + 
         'dy style="background:#aaf"><div style="padding:50px;line-height:50px;border:s' +
         'olid 1px black;">method #2: same domain<b' +
         'r />test2<br />test2</div></bo' + 'dy></ht' + 
         'ml>');
fd.close();
```

you can see it in action here: http://jsbin.com/ifevad

i hope this helps -ck

Comment: many thanks for this. Voted up for a full and complete answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

This very same example worked for me, in Chrome 17, on Windows, with the given html files:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="index2.html" id="test">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

index2.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div id="test_div">
    Ohai
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I used this in the chrome developer window:

```
i = document.getElementById('test')
doc = i.contentWindow.document
data=doc.getElementById('test_div');
i.style.height = data.offsetHeight + 'px'
```

The only catch was that it didn't work when opening the .html files directly - I had to start a web server.
I used this (it's the default Python server):

server.py

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8080

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: I don't really want to go down this route, is there another way?

Comment: or is it that chrome will always see a barrier when trying to access files that are not indicated directly in the URL. I am thinking that if the iframe page reference were sent through the url and applied to a frame through Javasrcip then there could be a better outcome, what do you think?

Comment: What do you mean "don't want to go down this route?" Do you not host your websites? Chrome(indeed, all browsers, I should think) does not allow you to access iframes from sites that are not on the same domain as you.

Comment: i know this, this is the same origin policy. All my files are in the same location so therefore access should be allowed across all pages, I am trying to work out why Chrome will not work, I do not think that opening a server is entirely required.

Comment: Well, when you open a page as file://, it is opened in a different way than normally. So the same origin policy will still stop you from accessing iframes. Are you saying that you're trying to create a website that you aren't going to host?